# Can not fetching yahoo mail by POP3 protocol by javamail

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-mail

I have some code below:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();

        //set mail protocol 
        //props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "pop3s");

        //create new store 
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        //store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store = session.getStore("pop3s");


        store.connect("pop.mail.yahoo.com", 995, "MyYahooUserName", "MyPassword");
        //store.connect("imap.next.mail.yahoo.com", 993, "MyYahooUserName", "MyPassword");
        isConnect = true;
```

It's work when I try IMAP protocol, but with POP3 I got exception below and I don't know why

```
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: EOF on socket
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:208)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at gmailutilities.GmailUtilities.connect(GmailUtilities.java:88)
at gmailutilities.Main.main(Main.java:29)
javax.mail.MessagingException: Not connected
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.checkConnected(POP3Store.java:408)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getDefaultFolder(POP3Store.java:357)
at gmailutilities.GmailUtilities.openFolder(GmailUtilities.java:103)
at gmailutilities.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

**Any one know why? Plz help me. Thanks all! **

Comment: Please read these [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) entries: - [How do I debug my application that uses JavaMail APIs?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) - [What are some of the most common mistakes people make when using JavaMail?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) You haven't included enough code to show where the error occurs, but [this FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#pop3folder) might be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Note that free Yahoo! Mail accounts do not allow POP3 or SMTP access. You must purchase a Yahoo! Mail Plus account to get POP3 and SMTP access.